# Allowing only one command perline in DSL

Tags: dsl, xtext

In my grammar I want atmost one command per line (I dont want ';' or ':' to terminate my commands). 
But when I use ('\r'?'\n') to ensure one command per line, it produces an extra line gape. for example it produces:

```
read Ram 03DF

write Ram 05FF

JMP Add 056A

CHK Reg 08AA
```

this is not required.  Expected should be without extra line wrap. For example:

```
read Ram 03DF
write Ram 05FF
JMP Add 056A
CHK Reg 08AA
```

the overview of what I am doing is

```
Model:
 (content += Elements ('\r'?'\n') )+
;
Elements:
Data | Path | Ram | Address
;
.
.
.
```

I am not sure how can I achieve that: Please help. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not model new lines in the grammar since it has no influence on the semantics! But in case of pretty printing a line break makes sense after each element. Your grammar fragment should look like this:

```
Model:
    content+=Element+;
Element:
    Data | Path | Ram | Address;
...
```

What you are looking for is the `org.your.dsl.formatting.YourDslFormatter` class. It provides a method stub to implement formatting patterns for pretty printing. There you define that a line break will be inserted after each `Element`. Try to start with s.th. like this:

```
class YourDslFormatter {
    @Inject YourDslGrammarAccess g
    override protected void configureFormatting(FormattingConfig c) {
        c.setLinewrap(1).after(g.elementRule)
    }
}
```

Everytime you trigger Eclipse's autoformat (ctrl + shift + F) your code will be pretty printed in the editor.